# How did Yoda know that Anakin killed the younglings before watching the security hologram?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, yoda

In Episode III, before Obi-Wan started watching the security holograms, Yoda already warned him:

> **YODA:** If into the security recordings you go, only pain will you find.

Obviously he was talking about Anakin... But how did Yoda know in advance that Anakin killed those younglings? Obi-Wan was full surprised to see that!

Comment: It's not clear that Yoda did know what they were going to see. Regardless, it was clear that watching the footage was bound to lead to nothing good.

Comment: Yoda has an incredible connection to the Force. It's possible that he sensed Anakin's presence in the temple

Comment: Yoda had sensed the evil in Anakin's heart before, so there's a possibility that Anakin left some kind of force residue or something behind which Yoda picked up on.

Comment: @Richard - Yes, and I was thinking also about when Yoda sees a dead youngling and say `Killed not by clones, this Padawan. By a lightsaber, he was.` - Maybe then he started putting the pieces together...

Comment: Qui-Gon can be heard trying to stop Anakin during the slaughter of the Tusken Raiders. At some point during or prior to the events of Revenge of the Sith, Qui-Gon begins communicating with Yoda. It's possible that Yoda knows because Qui-Gon told him.

Comment: Through training and been so old to achieve it Yoda has a connection with all the Jedi's. He feels things and events through the force in the Galaxy. At the point when the emperor gives the order 66 and all the Jedi start getting killed you can see Yoda is in Pain. So he was aware what was going on. Call it the 6th sense.

Comment: It's clear that Yoda feels the deaths, but not that he necessarily knows who killed whom via his Force connection.

Comment: Yoda may have watched the recording while Obi-Wan was disabling the beacon. I found the relevant clip on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=4cQjqv3iwwM#t=72). Yoda was standing in the room where the recording was while Obi-Wan was finishing with the beacon.

Comment: @Null: that's certainly how I interpreted that scene, as far as I remember. (I find ep. 3 to be the least watchable SW movie, so I might be remembering wrong.)

Comment: @phantom42: Really? Do you have a source for that? Liam Neeson was so disgusted by the low quality of *TPM* he refused to have anything else to do with Lucas. This is a man who has filmed three *Taken* movies.

Comment: @Martha: I'm pretty sure that's how I always interpreted it as well. It's been a while though.

Comment: @JamesSheridan you can hear his voice in Attack of the Clones during the slaughter scene. He yells, "Anakin! No!!" He has voice over scenes in the script for RotS, but I believe thy were cut to just a mention after by Yoda at the end when he tells Obi-Wan that Qui-Gon has new lessons for Obi-Wan.

Comment: @phantom42: So they dubbed in some of his comments from *TPM* when Neeson refused to do any more appearances? Typical Lucas voice-dubbing crap. I'm surprised they didn't replace his head.

Comment: Pretty sure that Anakin asking if Obi-Wan had been there, was to retcon Episode IV Vader saying "a presence I haven't felt since..." I actually think Yoda was part of a larger effort to frame Anakin. That's why he was the only one who "knew" that it was Anakin who killed the younglings. And that's why he, and Ghost Obi-wan, In ep IV, were so sketchy about telling Luke what happened to his father.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An earlier scene in Episode III shows Yoda reacting quite negatively as Anakin first takes a dip into the Dark Side.  It's likely he already suspected from this that Anakin was turning evil.  I believe it was at the exact time Anakin was killing the younglings.

He may not have known exactly what happened (like how in Episode IV, Obi-Wan knew something terrible had happened, but not yet that Alderran had been destroyed), but given the events that had transpired, coupled with this feeling, he may have been able to put the two together.

Comment: Adding to that, I just remembered something at Episode III... Anakin wakes up at home, then asks Padme: `"Obi-Wan was here, wasn't he?"` - So, a Force sensitive must be able to identify one's unique presence, even after he left... That would match the comments on the question, that suggested that Yoda might have felt Anakin's presence...

Comment: @LcSalazar Sounds like an entirely seperate answer....which I encourage you to post.  After all, answering your own question is a fully accepted practice on SE.  :)

Answer (score 9):

In the novelization it is clear that Yoda does know who did it:

> Obi-Wan stepped over white-armored bodies to kneel beside blaster-burned corpses of children. Tears flowed freely down tracks that hadn't had a chance to dry since he'd first entered the Temple.
>
> "Not even the younglings survived. It looks like they made a stand here."
>
> Yoda's face creased with ancient sadness. "Or trying to flee they were, with some turning back to slow the pursuit."
>
> Obi-Wan turned to another body, an older one, a Jedi fully mature and beyond. Grief punched a gasp from his chest. "Master Yoda—it's the Troll..."
>
> Yoda looked over and nodded bleakly. "Abandon his young students, Cin Drallig would not."
>
> Obi-Wan sank to his knees beside the fallen Jedi. "He was my lightsaber instructor..."
>
> "And his, was I," Yoda said. "Cripple us, grief will, if let it we do."
>
> "I know. But... it's one thing to know a friend is dead, Master Yoda. It's another to find his body..."
>
> "Yes." Yoda moved closer. With his gimer stick, he pointed at a bloodless gash in Drallig's shoulder that had cloven deep into his chest. "Yes, it is. See this, do you? This wound, no blaster could make."
>
> An icy void opened in Obi-Wan's heart. It swallowed his pain and his grief, leaving behind a precariously empty calm.
>
> He whispered, "A lightsaber?"
>
> "Business with the recall beacon, have we still." Yoda pointed with his stick at figures winding toward them among the trees and pools. "Returning, the clones are."
>
> Obi-Wan rose. "I will learn who did this."
>
> "Learn?" Yoda shook his head sadly. "Know already, you do," he said, and hobbled off into the gloom.

What is not very clear (at least not in absolute and digested terms at that very moment) is exactly how he knew.  But, throughout the novelization and the movies Yoda's distrust and general "bad feeling about this" towards Anakin is very apparent.  He knows what Anakin is capable of through his inability to control his anger ever since he was a child.  He also knows that Anakin has mastered the lightsaber to an extent where he would easily defeat Cin Drallig (Yoda's own student) who was protecting the children.  So it is not entirely inconcievable that knowing a lightsaber did the killing, Yoda would put two and two together and come up with Anakin as the culprit.

Comment: The novelisation is also around 1000 times better than the film, so this might just have been Stover covering Lucas's mistakes again.

Comment: @JamesSheridan I don't know, the novelisation was pretty bad...

Answer (score 8):

A quote from Episode III came to my mind regarding to this matter.

When Anakin wakes up in his loft, after another nightmare, he asks Padme:

> **Anakin:** Obi-Wan was here, wasn't he?

It may lead us to assume that a Force sensitive must be able to identify one's unique presence, even after he left. That would be enough to conclude that Yoda might have felt Anakin's strong dark presence at the temple.

Comment: But this does not explain why Obi-Wan didn't.

Answer (score 6):

An interpretation which does not require the Force to explain Yoda's knowledge: **Yoda may have watched the recording while Obi-Wan was disabling the beacon**.

If you watch the scene carefully, you'll notice that Yoda was standing in the room where the recording was while Obi-Wan was finishing with the beacon. Yoda would have had time to view the recording while Obi-Wan was busy with and distracted by the beacon.

The other answers argue that Yoda put two and two together and suspected or concluded that Anakin was the culprit as a result of Anakin's flirtation with the dark side. This is certainly a possibility, but would not necessarily offer the definitive proof of Anakin's guilt that the security recording did. Moreover, Obi-Wan would be just as aware as Yoda -- if not more -- of Anakin's dark side tendencies so it is not clear why *only* Yoda would be able use this knowledge to conclude that it was Anakin.

In case you don't have the film readily available, the relevant clip is on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=4cQjqv3iwwM#t=72).

Note: I originally posted this as a comment to the question, but I got some upvotes and other comments of agreement on it so I've promoted it to an answer.